# Highchart - Bell curve fill colour based on percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

What am i working on is, to create a bell curve and a fill the curve with colour to show that you have got `50 %` or `60 %` etc.

What i have done till now is:
Created a bell curve using `spline chart` in `highcharts`, now I want to limit the colour inside the chart based on the user percentage. I have no idea how this can be done in the highchart, Could anyone point me in the right direction.

I have tried to change the colour based on the http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/33/Multicolor%20series, but it have affected the bell curve.

Here is the fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/decs7eg1/5/

```
$(function () {
   $('#container').highcharts({
     chart: {
        type: 'areaspline'
     },
     title: {
        text: 'Average score'
     },
     legend: {
        enabled:false
     },
     xAxis: {
        categories: [
            '0',
            '25',
            '50',
            '75',
            '100'
         ]
     },
     yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Fruit units'
        }
     },
     tooltip: {
        enabled:false
     },
     credits: {
        enabled: false
     },
     plotOptions: {
        enabled:false
     },
     series: [ {
        name: 'Jane',
        data: [0, 0.5, 2, 0.5, 0]
     }]
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't achieve the same output by using `areaspline` type of `highchart`

I am adding two demos one with using `areaspline` and other with simple `line` chart use according to your requirements:

1. **areaspline:** http://jsfiddle.net/decs7eg1/8/
2. **line:** http://jsfiddle.net/decs7eg1/7/
3. **Vertical areaspline:** http://jsfiddle.net/decs7eg1/10/

To do this just add these lines in your code:

```
zones: [{
               value: 0,
               color: 'red'
            }, {
               value: 0.5,
               color: 'yellow'
            }, {
                value: 1,
               color: 'blue'
            }, {
                value: 2,
               color: 'green'
            }]
```

For further references refer to this link: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series

Comment: You mean in DEMO #1.?

Comment: Worm, thanks for the reply, is it possible to apply single colour from left to right, i mean vertically

Comment: You have to do some modifications in it, To design it accordingly..  You got the ingredients now just bake the cake :)

Comment: Working great mate, just last one question, is it possible to have different colour for the outline of the spline, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/decs7eg1/12/ , since have applied white colour the spline is not visible. Is it possible to apply different colour for the spline

Comment: I guess no for this you have to use `line` chart But I am not sure.